# Can I take my liquid medication on a plane?

Tags: usa, air-travel, health, airport-security, honduras

If I am taking a liquid medicine, but is over the ounces for a flight, will they still let me take it on a plane?

Comment: Flying to Honduras

Comment: The from matters too, where are you starting?

Answer (score 13):

Yes.
According to the [TSA website,](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/specialneeds/#content) but you will have to declare them to security personel and they will have to be x-rayed

> we are continuing to permit
>   prescription liquid medications and
>   other liquids needed by persons with
>   disabilities and medical conditions...
>
> However, if the liquid medications are
>   in volumes larger than 3.4 ounces
>   (100ml) each, they may not be placed
>   in the quart-size bag and must be
>   declared to the Transportation
>   Security Officer. A declaration can be
>   made verbally, in writing, or by a
>   person's companion, caregiver,
>   interpreter, or family member.
>
> Declared liquid medications and other
>   liquids for disabilities and medical
>   conditions must be kept separate from
>   all other property submitted for x-ray
>   screening.

Answer (score 6):

If you're flying out of the states you can take it in carry-on provided you declare that it's over 3.4 oz.

It's always easier if you can pack it but it's understandable if you can't. If you have a prescription I would bring it just incase.

[Source](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/customer/editorial_1029.shtm)